# Get the html from another webpage from another machine

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the html of this page: http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/default.asp and from this page go to 'Drumuri' where the cars is placed.
For short I am trying to get that tabel from 'Drumuri ' page.
I have tried this code:

```
<?php
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML('http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/default.asp');


$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

print_R($items);
?>
```

And I also tried with cURL, but no results. This my county's website and I think it is very secured so that's why I can not get it's html. Can you please try and give me the right answer. If I can or not and how or why?

Comment: do a `var_dump` on `$items`. Also, its `print_r`, not `print_R`

Comment: Yep, there is a security :  Warning: file_get_contents(http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/default.asp): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in D:\UwAmp\www\index.php on line 3

Comment: @mehul mohan so then please give me the code to get it's html please. And it is not a very big difference between print_r and print_R . They both do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load directly http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/default.asp because it contains iFrame. The iFrame source is http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/dreapta.asp

Here is how to go thru the links and find the `DRUMURI` link:

```
<?php
$baseUrl = 'http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/';

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTMLFile($baseUrl.'dreapta.asp');

foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    if ($link->nodeValue == 'DRUMURI') {
        echo "Label -> ".$link->nodeValue."\n";
        echo "Link -> ".$baseUrl.$link->getAttribute('href')."\n";
    }
}
```

->

```
Label -> DRUMURI
Link -> http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/drumuri.asp
```

Comment: I was about to say that. +1

Comment: @Gab From where did you get 'dreapta.asp ' on third line? I have copied your code  and it is giving me this errors:Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag marquee invalid in http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/dreapta.asp, line: 59 in C:\xampp\htdocs\get.php on line 6
Label -> DRUMURI Link -> http://213.177.10.50:6060/itn/drumuri.asp

Comment: @JohnDavid the error is because the HTML is invalid in thee page. I found `dreapta.asp` looking into the source of the original page